# Angular-Chart.js - Tooltip not working with 0 values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, chart.js

In my Angular Chart JS Application could it be that there are "0" values in my data array. If I have "0" values, the tooltip is not working for this bar. When I change it to "0.1" its working...

The Issue appears only in IE10/11 - In Firefox its working fine.

Anybody has a suggestion how to solve it ?

Here is my Code and link to a plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/p0bepcBrfQ31EoZsrtso

```
 <body>
<div ng-controller="jsonServerBox">
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="module in ocw.modules" ng-style="{'background-color': module.background, 'color': module.fontcolor, 'border': module.border}">
    <div class=""><canvas id="base" class="chart chart-base" widht="" chart-type="module.type" chart-data="module.data" chart-labels="module.labels" chart-series="module.series" chart-colours="module.colors" chart-options="module.options"></canvas></div>              
  </li>
</ul>
```

And JSON File:

```
{"modules":[{

        "border":"1px solid rgb(69, 69, 69)",
        "background":"rgb(69, 69, 69)",
        "fontcolor":"white",
        "type":"Bar",
        "series":"SeriesA",
        "data":[[0, 0.1,20,20]],
        "labels":["A","B","S","O"],
        "colors":[{
                "fillColor":"white",
                "strokeColor":"white",
                "pointColor":null,
                "pointStrokeColor":"",
                "pointHighlightFill":"transparent",
                "pointHighlightStroke":"white"
                }],
        "options":{
                "scaleShowGridLines":false,
                "pointHitDetectionRadius":2,
                "barValueSpacing":1,
                "scaleBeginAtZero":false                    
                }
        }]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just increase (or remove) the `pointHitDetectionRadius` to a larger value (it'll work even if you increase the chart size, but I assume that's not an option) and you'll see the tooltips (I checked in IE11 in IE10 mode - the tooltips were not appearing on the Plnkr screen unless I either increased `pointHitDetectionRadius` or expanded the window to make the chart bigger)

Comment: thanks - increasing the chart size is basically not an option (but also saw that with a greater chart size its working). how much did you increase the pointHitDetectionRadius that it was working ?

Comment: I just removed the pointHitDetectionRadius - that would have made it the default value (I think that's 20).